# Use stored salt in concat

Tags: mysql

Consider the following query which returns the same output whether the username is invalid or whether the password is wrong (just an example, I know about SQL Injection):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR(64),
    password CHAR(40)
);

SELECT FROM users
      WHERE username = '{$username}'
        AND password = sha1('{$password}');
```

I would like to add a salt field, but rather than retrieve it and concatenate in the application, I would prefer that MySQL do the concatenation in the engine:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR(64),
    salt VARCHAR(128),
    password CHAR(40)
);

SELECT FROM users
      WHERE username = '{$username}'
        AND password = sha1(CONCAT(<salt_field>, '{$password}'));
```

What would I replace `<salt_field>` with?

Comment: `sha1(CONCAT(salt, '{$password}'))`. Salt refers to the column in the users table, just like querying it with a join or in a select.

Comment: You should not put the plain password in the query because enabled query logging would expose the passwords. Do the hashing in your application, not in SQL.

Comment: @Caramiriel: Thank you, please post that as an answer so that I might accept it.

Comment: @fab: For that purpose the 'real' query is actually doubly-hashed, so the end result is `md5(concat(salt, md5(password)))`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to any column as you'd like. In this case you can use `WHERE password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, <password>))`. Note that the password still can be sniffed. It's up to you if you trust the environment. A good example, but less useful, is the following query: `WHERE lastName = username`. In this case you will compare the last name of the user with the username that they have chosen. So in this case it will return all users that have the same username as their last name.

This also happens when you join multiple tables. In fact, you join all rows of the first table with the rows in the second table, but only return the ones that match the given criteria. Clever optimalization will result in not considering all possible combinations, but just a fraction of them.

Comment: Thank you for putting the issue in contexts where I was familiar with the concept.